# Jquery - Keeping datas after post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, post

I'm trying to loop a jquery post request and stopping it when the result data is correct.

```
while(flag == 0){
    $.post("file.php", {
        first:first_p,
        second:second_p
    }, function(data){
            if(data == 1){
                flag = 1;
            }
    }
}
```

But the problem seems to be that flag is only available within the post request and not the while loop.
How can I solve this problem?
Thanks.

Comment: where have you declared flag...please post full code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because ajax takes time to query the server, and during that time it will continue to send requests, while it's in the `while` loop.

It would be a better design to to wrap your code in a function, and if an incorrect response has been provided, ie `data` is not `1`, then call the function again.

```
function checkFile(){
    $.post("file.php", {
        first:first_p,
        second:second_p
    }, function(data){
        if(data == 1){
            flag = 1;
        } else {
           checkFile();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. Indeed I was trying to delay the response because I was expecting a time issue. Thanks again.